# spectrogram by fft using python

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to understand a piece of code which in my opinion trying to apply filter first and then compute FFT. 
I don't understand how it is doing that. Can anyone please explain that to me. 
Here is the code:

```
# Parameters to create the spectrogram
N = 160000  # No. of frames in .wav file
K = 512  
step = 4
wind = 0.5 * (1 - np.cos(np.array(range(K)) * 2 * np.pi / (K - 1)))  # 0.5*2*sin(o/2), creation of filter window
ffts = []
def wav_to_floats(file):
    s = wave.open(file, 'r')
    str_sig = s.readframes(s.getnframes())
    y = np.fromstring(str_sig, np.short)
    s.close()    
    return y

for file_index in range(len(label)):
    test_flag = label.iloc[file_index]['fold'] # 0 - training data, 1 - test data
    fname = label.iloc[file_index]['filename']

    #-------------from here i dont understand mainly------------ 
    spectogram = []
    s = wav_to_floats(essential_folder+'src_wavs/'+fname+'.wav')
    for j in range(int((step*N/K) - step)):
        vec = s[j * K/step : (j+step) * K/step] * wind
        spectogram.append(abs(fft(vec, K)[:K / 2]))

    ffts.append(np.array(spectogram))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it converts the file from wav to float( `s = wav_to_floats(essential_folder+'src_wavs/'+fname+'.wav'`)`
, because to calculate fft you need a float number. After that, it does the convolution between the signal and the window(probably a windowed filter)

```
for j in range(int((step*N/K) - step)):
        vec = s[j * K/step : (j+step) * K/step] * wind
```

takes the modulus of the fft (because fft gives to you a complex number which carries information about modulus and phase) and adds this vector to ffts